# Export & Import JMS messages as XML Programmatically

Tags: jms

Iam a newbie to JMS .  I want to export and import the JMS messages programmatically to a queue(I dont want to use admin console) . Can somebody provide some pointers ...

Comment: JMS isn't for that sort of thing. You'd need to talk directly to the underlying JMS implementation, whatever that is (and you didn't tell us).

Answer (score 0):

\';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\\';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\\";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//-->\">\'>